# how to create a SharePoint modern list with links to external sites with icons

Tags: url, sharepoint, font-awesome, external

I'd like to have a list of external URLs and also use font awesome icons in front of each of them. I first created a list with a link and an icon, but I don't think this is correct, and it just doesn't look right.
I thought the embed web part might be the way to do this, but I'm not so sure.
What is the best way to do this?
thanks

created a list of urls and have images for each link but it looks odd and clumsy. I've been searching for a while now, and haven't found anything that works.

Comment: Please provide more details on this matter: Are you using SharePoint online modern site? Are there any special requirements for icons that need to be added? Can you provide the results of your previous attempts?

Comment: hi, I was able to use Quicklinks to accomplish this - thank you